# How can I prevent foreign changes to my Windows 10 "Group Policies" by firewall rules?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, activesync

Specifically, I would like to use the Windows 10 firewall to block changes to Group Policy from sources other than me.

My computer is not for corporate use, not for use on corporate networks. I do not want to see another ActiveSync Policy Broker popup.

If I want to make changes to my computer's security and related policies, I'll do it myself. I don't want others participating in administrating my machine.

I want to be able to continue to use (personal) Office365.

- The Group Policy Client service cannot be disabled as far as I can see.
- I have renamed C:\Windows\System32\gpupdate as some have suggested, and it hasn't stopped the popups.

I've seen lots of discussion on this subject, but no concrete facts about how to remove or disable it. Period.

Comment: "The group policy update system service cannot be disabled as far as I can see." I cannot for the life of me figure out which policy/feature your talking about.  Your question seems to be about ActiveSync but that statement seems to talk about Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound - I edited the question to correctly state the name of the service: "Group Policy Client". Thank you for helping me make this question better.

Comment: If you are running a Professional or Enterprise version of Windows you won't be able to get rid of that service. You can prevent ActiveSync by simply not using a client that supports connecting to Exchange servers.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have several machines with "Windows 10 Home". But, as a programmer and sysadmin, I can't accept the answer "you won't be able to get rid of that service" even if it's for a Pro or Enterprise version. I specified that "blocking" the service is an acceptable solution, however, if what you mean is that it "can't be removed", I don't accept that either. If you mean is there is no procedure "blessed by Microsoft", then that's outside the scope of my intention with this question. Also, a fairly extensive search hasn't turned up procedures recommended by Microsoft in this context.

Comment: Windows 10 always has policies applied to it. The only difference between a corporate-managed computer vs a personal computer is the source of the policies. You cannot disable Group Policy even on a personal computer because substantial portions of how your computer functions are determined by it. Active Sync, on the other hand, is just one method MS products communicate with each other and has precious little to do with Microsoft's fingers in your pie. If your issue is that you want to figure out how to block the AS Policy Broker pop-up, please further narrow your question as it is written.

Comment: Very useful comment (to me). So what ARE the non-corporate sources of policies? How can they be controlled and/or blocked? As an outsider, it seems Windows 10 admins are being secretive/coy about this functionality, which strikes me as insecure (for me as the owner/user of my PC). My bottom line here is I wish to secure my Windows 10 Home PC. In the absence of a reply, I will continue to refine and search for answers. Thanks.

Comment: @HughBuntu - The source would be whatever the default is for a specific policy.  While Windows 10 Home cannot join a domain or edit the local group policy, it still uses those defaults, as evident by the fact you can manually add the editor and it will use those polciies you configure..

Comment: @music2myear "...block the AS Policy Broker pop-up" seems ambiguous, as most answers either (1) assume it's a corporate PC or (2) assume you're OK with having your PC remote controlled. Put another way, specifically I'd like to automatically and always answer "No" to the pop-up - as if there were a checkbox for that on the dialogue box. Do you have a suggestion for how to word that properly in Microsoft-ese? Thanks!

Comment: @ramhound thanks, but that doesn't help me clarify the question or find an answer. Where are the "defaults" you mention stored, and how can they be changed? Thanks!

Comment: @HughBuntu - If you don't want the default configured of "not configured" you would have to specify if you want the specific group policy either enabled or disabled.  You will be unable to change the behavior of "not configured"

Comment: That is a fair point @HughBuntu, but I think you still have some strong assumptions about how Windows 10 settings work that aren't necessarily based in reality, and so the answers that ARE based in reality may not appeal to you. We may prefer that something behave a certain way, but as we didn't author the program we actually have very little say in the matter.

Comment: Suffice to say: If you are using a personal version of Windows that YOU have not connected to any external policy source such as a domain, the ONLY things making changes on that system will be programs YOU have installed or things baked-in to the operating system. Security software, patches and updates, application installations, all these have the ability to make changes to your firewall and other system settings. When UAC prompts for approval, it is because a program is asking to change something or write something to a part of the system that MAY have an affect like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to (1) part is there a firewall formula... ?

**UNTESTED**

I found several docs on the web that purport to provide port usage information for ActiveSync. I can't vouch for their accuracy or completeness at this time.

I also went out and bought a managed switch for IGMP snooping so I can monitor traffic to determine the effectiveness of filters based on this information.

Here is a digest of what I've found:

Microsoft ActiveSync uses the following applications for the communication:
* Wcesmgr.exe
* Wcescomm.exe
* Rapimgr.exe

Microsoft ActiveSync uses the following ports for the communication:

```
1. Inbound TCP:  
    * 990  
    * 999  
    * 5678  
    * 5721  
    * 26675  
2. Inbound UDP:
    * 2883  
3. Outbound UDP:  
    * 5679
```